# error: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY

Tags: xorg, compiz, dconf, reset

I urgently need to reset Compiz to its default settings because my desktop doesn't show the Dash or menu bar.

When I type:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

It says:

```
error: Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY

Usage:
  dconf reset [-f] PATH

Reset a key or a dir. -f is required for dirs.

Arguments:
   PATH          Either a KEY or DIR
   KEY           A key path (starting, but not ending with '/')
   DIR           A directory path (starting and ending with '/')
```

What to do next?

Best regards

Comment: I am wondering why gsettings would require X11 at all.

Answer (score 5):

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

if you see

```
Xlib: connection to ":0.0" refused by server
Xlib: No protocol specified

Error: Can't open display: :0.0
```

then

```
xhost +
```

Answer (score -1):

You could replace your current instance of compiz with the following command from a tty.

```
DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace
```

You can probably also do:

```
DISPLAY=:0 dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

Comment: down vote
accept
 

It didn't work

DISPLAY=:0 compiz --replace compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core No protocol specified compiz (core) - Fatal: Couldn't open display :0 compiz (core) - Info: Stopping plugin: core compiz (core) - Info: Unloading plugin: core

DISPLAY=:0 dconf reset -f /org/compiz error: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=68be4fa5ac7f2cedb6855a8b5558734d --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1