# Ubuntu login loop problem

Tags: login

After I updated the packages on my Ubuntu 14.04LTS, my Ubuntu virtual machine that I was running on parallels wont let me log in. Also it won't work for the guest account.

This is the error-log output: `xsessions-error`

[image: error message]

Also if I run any `sudo apt-get` commands I get the following error:

```
apt-get: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot ch file or directory
```

Comment: Few minutes before you I posted the same...

Comment: I think you have to reboot and go to the "system recovery" menu, there you should repair broken packages and then dpkg. I'm not sure if this actually works, but it should if something's broken.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) or [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/590561/ubuntu-14-04-login-loop-problem)?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to a TTY (ctrl-alt-f1). You may restart between each step to see if that worked.

```
sudo rm -r ~/.config/compiz*
sudo rm -r ~/.cache/compizconfig-1
```

**Clear the cache**

```
sudo rm -r .cache/
```

**Reset Unity**

```
sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
setsid unity
```

Comment: Can this harm my files? And how to get out of tty3 to get in tty?

Comment: P.S. I need all those settings and files I had to be the same as they were...

Comment: Mark, the terminal is NOT accessible... I tried ctrl + alt + T, but in login screen it doesn't let it...

Comment: @markkirby As mentioned in the original post he can't get past the login screen. It's something I'd try and I'm no expert. I'm just trying to help. It's not copy paste BTW.

Comment: Sorry I must of missed that for some reason. Please accep my apologies.

Comment: Hi there, I tried the steps given above and when it comes to Reset Unity, the first command gives me an error which says: "Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY". I have found another thread with a similar problem but it was never solved [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/645968/error-cannot-autolaunch-d-bus-without-x11-display)